# Свойства(автосвойства) в c# это поведение или состояние объекта?

Tags: c#, .net, ооп

Собственно, вопрос: свойства(автосвойства) в c# это поведение или состояние объекта?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Определимся с терминологией:

1. > ***Объект*** обладает состояние и поведение.([Гради Буч](http://www.helloworld.ru/texts/comp/other/oop/ch03.htm))

   Подчеркну еще раз **объект**. Не тип, не класс(класс **только описывает** будущий объект), а **объект**.
2. > ***Состояние*** объекта характеризуется перечнем (обычно статическим) всех свойств данного объекта и текущими (обычно динамическими) значениями каждого из этих свойств.(см. ссылку в пункте №1)
3. > ***Поведение*** - это то, как объект действует и реагирует; поведение выражается в терминах состояния объекта и передачи сообщений. Иными
   >   словами, поведение объекта - это его наблюдаемая и проверяемая извне
   >   деятельность.(см. ссылку в пункте №1)
4. > ***Свойство*** — это член, предоставляющий гибкий механизм для чтения,
   >   записи или вычисления значения частного поля. Свойства можно
   >   использовать, как если бы они были членами общих данных, но фактически
   >   они **представляют собой специальные методы**, называемые методами
   >   доступа. Это позволяет легко получать доступ к данным и помогает
   >   повысить безопасность и гибкость методов. (ссылку на MSDN смотри внизу)
5. > ***Свойства***  позволяют  обращаться  к  методу  в исходном тексте
   >   программы, используя упрощенный синтаксис.(Ссылка на Рихтера смотри внизу)
6. > ***Осторожный подход к определению свойств.*** Лично мне свойства не
   >   нравятся, и я был бы рад, если бы их поддержку убрали из Microsoft
   >   .NET Framework и сопутствующих языков программирования. **Причина в 
   >   том,  что  свойства  выглядят  как  поля,  на  самом  деле  являясь 
   >   методами.**  Это  по рождает массу заблуждений и непонимания.
   >   Столкнувшись с кодом, обращающимся к  полю,  разработчик  привычно 
   >   предполагает  наличие  массы  условий,  которые просто не всегда
   >   верны, если речь идет о свойстве. (Ссылка на Рихтера смотри внизу)

А теперь разберемся, что к чему. 
Пример из того же Рихтера глава 9.

```
public sealed class Employee 
{
private String m_Name;   // Это состояние 
private Int32  m_Age;    // Это состояние 

public String GetName() // Это поведение  
{
   return(m_Name);
}
public void SetName(String value) // Это поведение
{
   m_Name = value;
}
```

Равносилен этому примеру из той же главы (Рихтер об это сам и говорит):

```
public sealed class Employee 
{
   private String m_Name; // Это состояние 
   private Int32  m_Age; // Это состояние 

   public String Name // Это поведение  
   {
     get { return(m_Name); }
     set { m_Name = value; }
   }  
}
```

Тут уже становится ясно что свойства это **механизм** доступа к закрытым полям, который осуществляется через методы. А значит, что **Свойства это поведение**. Рихтер как раз и критикует свойства, за то что они похожи на поля, а на самом деле это методы (которые предоставляет доступ к закрытым полям). Рихтер вообще предлагает убрать свойства, дабы избежать путаницы (в книге он рассматривает проблему со свойствами с другой стороны, но это еще одна грань проблем связаны с свойствами).

И, по-поводу свойства в интерфейсах, они помечаются как abstract, и выглядят примерно так:

```
public abstract String GetName();
public abstract void SetName(String value);
```

Это просто голые методы без реализации. Они не могут быть ни состояние, ни поведение, так как только **ОБЪЕКТ** может иметь состояние и поведение. Экземпляр интерфейса и абстрактного класса нельзя создать, по этому к ним применение понятия состояния и поведения невозможно.

Ссылки:

**I.** [Ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) на MSDN (Определение свойства).

**II.** [Ссылка](http://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/135083/Rihter_-_CLR_via_C%23._Programmirovanie_na_platforme_Microsoft_.NET_Framework_2.0_na_yazyke_C%23.pdf) на Рихтера (Определение свойства, 9 глава стр. 204 по книге).

Comment: В оригинале рихтер не предлагает убрать свойства из .NET, он просто сожалеет что они есть: "Personally, I don’t like properties and I wish that they were not supported in the Microsoft .NET Framework and its programming languages.". И опять же, свойства в C# добавлены не только ради того, что они позволяют красиво объявить два метда. Они добавлены ради метаданных, которые на эту пару методов навешиваются. По сравнению с языками, в которых метаданных нет (например, старой Java) - да, это кажется ненужным усложнением.

Comment: Если нужно добавить больше ссылок - пишите в комментариях, или вставляйте как обычный текст - кто-нибудь вставит в тело поста.

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо за правку. Вы правы, он сожалеет о том что они есть, но так же во второй части предложения предлагает убрать поддержку свойств (мне кажется это тождественно удалению). В этой главе о Свойствах, он прямо говорит что отказался бы от свойств  *If I
had been involved in the design of the .NET Framework and compilers, I would have not offered
properties at all; instead, I would have programmers actually implement GetXxx and SetXxx methods
as desired.*  http://www.johnchukwuma.com/training/clr_via_c_4th_edition.pdf  235 стр по сайту.

Answer (score 2):

Это фича языка / компилятора, которая генерирует одновременно поле класа (которое хранят состояние) и свойство в виде метаданных + двух методов доступа к этому свойству (поведение).

UP на основе комментариев от топикастера:

C# использует *похожий* синтаксис для объявления *обычных* свойств в интерфейсах и auto-implemented свойств в классах. Несмотря на схожий синтаксис, результат отличается.

В классах auto-implemented свойства задают одновременно и состояние, и поведение:

```
class SomeClass
{
    // компилятор создаст приватное поле + пару методов для доступа к нему
    int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

В интерфейсах свойства объявляются без тел геттеров и сеттеров - т.к. тела этих методов являются реализацией поведения, а C# не поддерживает включение реализации в интерфейс:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    // компилятор не создаст ни полей, ни методов
    int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Такое свойство может быть реализовано классом как угодно, в том числе в виде полной реализации get и set:

```
public class Class1 : ISomeInterface
{
    int _myField;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _myField;
        }
        set
        {
            _myField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Окей, свойство(автосвойсто) в интерфейсе это состояние или поведение? Разве автосвойсто генерирует скрытое поле в интерфейсе?

Comment: При чем здесь интерфейс? Объект интерфейса невозможно создать.

Comment: @Puh в интерфейсах нет автосвойств. там есть просто свойства, которые реализующий интерфейс класс волен реализовать как угодно.

Comment: @Puh и да, у интерфейса нет ни состояния, ни поведения :)

Comment: @PashaPash, как это в интерфейсах нет автосвойст? а это как https://ibb.co/kytuTa. Ок, если у интерфейса нет, ни состояния, ни поведения, то что с абстрактными классами? Свойста(автосвойста) в абс. классах это поведение или состояние?

Comment: @Puh Вы пошли по кругу. Автосвойство в абстрактном классe (если оно не обозначено как абстрактное) ничем не отличается от автосвойства в неабстрактном классе. А если оно декларировано как абстрактное, то не отличается от свойства в интерфейсе.

Comment: @Igor, окей, так какой ответ на вопрос? Свойства это поведение или состояние?

Comment: @Puh Так. Это возможность языка (syntactic sugar), которое ничем не отличается от явного объявления private поля и однострочных сетера и гетера. "Ты считаешь, что на любой вопрос можно ответить "да" или "нет"? Тогда отвечай, ты уже прекратила пить коньяк по утрам?" А. Линдгрен "Три повести о Малыше и Карлсоне"

Comment: @Puh пример по вашей ссылке - это *просто свойство* в интерфейсе. Оно означает, что класс, реализующий этот интерфейс, должен это в свойство как-то реализовать. Реализует ли он его в виде автосвойства, или обычного свойства - неизвестно.

Answer (score 1):

Обычный **синтаксический сахар.** Тоже что и `лямба выражения (анонимные функции)`. Тоже что и `Expression bodied functions` (=>), и `async/await`, и `Tuple`.
Этот сладкий, помогает очень сильно сократить код.

P.S: никто не мешает тебе написать:

```
private string _name;

public string Name
{
    //здесь тоже сахар
    get=> _name;
    set=> _name = value;
}
```

или так:

```
private string _name;

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return _name;
    }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
    }
}
```